# Control a form PHP

Tags: php, html, http-status-code-404

I got this form:

```
<form action="search.php" method="get" id="urlcreateform">
  <div class="input-append">
    <input class="span8 meela" id="q" name="q" type="text"><input style="display:none" type="radio" name="scl" value="Twitter" alt="flickr" checked></input><button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" id="submit" title="Submit Search">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

And when I type in for example `http://google.com/` it gives me this error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /search.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Any ideas how to fix that?
For example to replace the `http://` to empty and search?

Comment: check whether you have search.php file in the home folder

Comment: Chceck that you have a web server and PHP interpreter too...

Comment: 403 Forbidden is a Resource Permissions issue. Check for file permissions on search.php

Comment: This wont fix your problem, but it may prevent more in the future :: add a ; after display:none on your input

Answer (score 0):

try Cmhod 777

can you post some of your search. Sometimes a 503 is kicked back by the server over faulty code